# New content is showing up in a site: search for my old domain name, despite 301 redirects to new domain

Tags: google-search

So, I changed my website domain one week ago, made 301 redirect from the old domain to the new domain and told Google about the change in the Search Console.

However, some of the new pages (created after the domain change) are showing up in site: searches for the old domain.

What could be causing this?

Comment: How can you tell they are indexed with the old domain?    Even if they are, does it matter? Users get redirected.

Comment: I perform (site:old-domain.com) search and find out. Yes, they get redirected, but the indexing of my new domain is not performing well, I think this issue is related.

Comment: Google shows redirecting URLs during a site search.   That doesn't mean that is the version of the page that is actually indexed.   It just means that Google knows about those URLs.   If you search for a unique sentence from the article in quotes on Google, you should find it indexed on the correct URL.   Using `site:` searches is not accurate to determine index status.

Comment: If Google knows about these URLs, it means that something is linking to your new content with the old domain.   That something is likely to be your own site somewhere.    You should find that and fix it.

Comment: What happens if you wait 48 hours? Sometimes google needs to catch-on to the changes you made.